# How to make Ajax requests that will be save data?

Tags: ajax, django

I am working on project,which includes test.Questions from test has to come out randomly and must display one by one.There is button Next which you pressed when finish to answer to question.Then there must show other question.

I do it like below

```
$('btnEnd').click(function() {
            var rates = 
document.getElementsByClassName('button_radio')
            $("input:radio").each(function(){
                var name = $(this).attr("name")
                if($("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked")){
                    var radioValue = 
                        $("input[name="+name+"]:checked").val()

            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'test' id %}",
                data: {
                  'radioValue': radioValue
                },
                success: function (data) {

                }
              });
        }

def Test_view(request,id):
    install = User_table.objects.get(id=id)
    install.checking=True
    install.save()
    random_number =randint(45, 50)
    list_answered={}
    radioValue = request.GET.get('radioValue', None)
    list_answered['random']=radioValue;
 finance=Test.objects.filter(sections=1,data=date.today(),number=random_number);
    return render(request,'finance.html',{'finance':finance,'id':id})
```

Here url is for function Test_view

But it doesn't work,and i am not sure does it save answer or not ?

Comment: What does it mean `it doesn't work`? You need to do check in the database to see if it saved or not.

Comment: no it hasn't to save it in db,I am not sure does it save it in list_answer,because as i understand Ajax is like it call this function  again

Comment: But what are you expecting to save? The only thing you save here is the User_table object, where you update `checking` to True. You don't save the data from the radio button anywhere at all.

Answer (score -1):

The way you are passing the url in Ajax is wrong you need to pass hardcode url. I have done this kind of thing in project. Do like this:

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",
        url: "/olx/deletePhoto",
        data:{
          photo_id:photoId
        },
        success: function(){

        }
        });
```

For getting the selelcted radio button value like this:

```
  radioValue = $("input[name='cover-photo']:checked").val();
```

Comment: how it save photo_id every time?

Comment: Every time make ajax call.